# How geckofx is recognized by browser "detectors" (as Mozilla or my program name)?

Tags: c#, vb.net, webbrowser-control, mozilla, gecko

I want to create a web browser in visual basic. So..I used WebBrowser control but when I visited this website [https://www.whatismybrowser.com](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/) I realized that the program is recognized as Internet Explorer.. I searched for another options and I found GeckoFx, but before trying it I want to know if it is recognized as Mozilla or just my program name?

Comment: AFAIK, they use the user agent.

Comment: @Danh You mean the web "detectors" are using the user agent, right?

Comment: Maybe. I'm not sure. Try to change user agent and check

Comment: @Danh Yes, it is true..They use the user agent..But,how I change it in order to show my program name (and not internet explorer)?

Answer (score 1):

In Geckofx 33 or less -             Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["general.useragent.override"] = "user agent goes here";

In geckofx 45 things are different and it might be another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the sites know the exact name of your application - they know how to recognize certain browsers by certain patterns in the user agent string.

If you do end up using the WebBrowser control, keep the user agent what it is so sites treat it as IE, since that's what it uses to render everything.